# Continuously increasing memory usage when app running ( Swift )

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I am retrieving image data and string from document directory and use this data in a collection view in ViewController1. Then by clicking collection view cell go to next view controller ViewController2 and again retrieve image data and string from document directory and use this data in another collection view. Now problem is when I go from one view controller to another and back every time increasing memory usage and as a result app crash. What would be reason for this type of memory increasing and how I will solve it?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
let cell: PhotoThumbnail = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoThumbnail

 do{
            let ta = foldersDirectoryPath + "/\(self.titles2[indexPath.item])"
            print(ta)
            let ti = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(ta)
            print(ti.count)
            cell.amountLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.amountLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:16/255.0, green:56/255.0, blue:70/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
            cell.amountLabel.text = "\(ti.count)"


        }catch{

        }

        cell.setThumbnailImage(images[indexPath.item])
        let str = titles2[indexPath.item]
        let nameString = str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex.advancedBy(24), end: str.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))

        cell.nameLabel.text = nameString
        print(dateArray[indexPath.item])
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateArray[indexPath.item]

   return cell
}


class PhotoThumbnail: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgView : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

  func setThumbnailImage(thumbnailImage: UIImage){
    self.imgView.image = thumbnailImage
   }

}
```

This code is for 1st collection view.

Comment: Please make sure you are using `dequeueReusableCell` in `cellForItemAt indexPath` method. It will be batter If you can provide code of your collectionview so that I can help you to debug the issue.]

Comment: What is happening in the `setThumbnailImage(images[indexPath.item])` ? I guess it will be the code for generating the thumbnail from the image right? So basically that can make difference in memory consumption. Try by commenting that line temporarily and check the memory consumption to find out the problem. Rest of the code is looking fine to me.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain setThumbnailImage(images[indexPath.item]). images is a UIImage type array.

Comment: After analysing all the things it seems that the images you are setting in the image view seems very heavy except that nothing is looking wrong in this check the image size that is being set in collection view and try to reduce them if they are heavy.

Comment: Hard to tell if you dont put any code, try print something at `deinit()` and see if it ever got called

Comment: Apple provide the Allocations and Leaks instruments to enable you to find memory issues. What do these instruments show?

Comment: If anyone is interested, I can send my project. It would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

its creating multiple instances of the view's one and two. you should use a segue to pass data from one view to another, and back.

Comment: Have there another solution? I am facing some problem with segue and don't want to use segue. Now I am using present view controller with identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create all the declarations as optional and when you go from one view controller to another controller make a function to release all these objects. This will help to manage the memory issue.